# Mbed code problems

Tags: c++, debugging, mbed

My code has multiple errors and after few hours of debugging I cannot make it compile. This code should run in a loop whereby it will read and clarify into different colour categories. I also used a proximity sensor to activate the code.

The code will run in seven loops. In each loop, which I defined as `p`, it will put in clarified value from the function `rgb_process` into a stack called `block [p]`. The errors are as follows:

> ```
> Warning: Parameter "rgb_c" was set but never used in "main.cpp", Line: 22, Col: 49
> Warning: Parameter "rgb_r" was set but never used in "main.cpp", Line: 22, Col: 59
> Warning: Parameter "rgb_g" was set but never used in "main.cpp", Line: 22, Col: 69
> Warning: Parameter "rgb_b" was set but never used in "main.cpp", Line: 22, Col: 79
> Error: Identifier "rgb_readings" is undefined in "main.cpp", Line: 40, Col: 20
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 45, Col: 30
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 45, Col: 46
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 45, Col: 62
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 45, Col: 78
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 50, Col: 34
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 50, Col: 50
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 50, Col: 66
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 50, Col: 82
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 55, Col: 38
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 55, Col: 54
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 55, Col: 70
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 55, Col: 86
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 60, Col: 42
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 60, Col: 58
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 60, Col: 74
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 60, Col: 90
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 65, Col: 46
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 65, Col: 62
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 65, Col: 78
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 65, Col: 94
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 70, Col: 49
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 70, Col: 65
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 70, Col: 81
> Error: Expression must have pointer-to-object type in "main.cpp", Line: 70, Col: 97
> Error: Type name is not allowed in "main.cpp", Line: 101, Col: 28
> Error: Expected a ")" in "main.cpp", Line: 101, Col: 32
> Error: Too few arguments in function call in "main.cpp", Line: 101, Col: 32
> Error: Expected a ";" in "main.cpp", Line: 102, Col: 10
> Error: Type name is not allowed in "main.cpp", Line: 131, Col: 27
> ```

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "MCP23017.h"
#include "C12832.h"
#include "TCS3472_I2C.h"
#include "VL6180.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

DigitalOut RED_CHIP(p21);
DigitalOut BLUE_CHIP(p22);
DigitalOut GREEN_CHIP(p23);
DigitalOut Red(p23);
DigitalOut Green(p24);
DigitalOut Blue(p25);
TCS3472_I2C rgb_sensor(p9,p10);
C12832 lcd(p5,p7,p6,p8,p11);
Serial pc(USBTX,USBRX);
VL6180 TOF_sensor(p28,p27);

void coloursensorread (int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b)  //colour sensor read
{
    wait(3);

    rgb_sensor.enablePowerAndRGBC();
    rgb_sensor.setIntegrationTime(100);
    rgb_sensor.getAllColors(rgb_readings);
    rgb_c= rgb_readings[0];
    rgb_r= rgb_readings[1];
    rgb_g= rgb_readings[2];
    rgb_b= rgb_readings[3];

        //pc.printf("C:%d, R:%d, G:%d, B:%d\n",rgb_readings[0],rgb_readings[1],rgb_readings[2],rgb_readings[3]);
        wait(2);
}

void rgb_process(int p,int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int block [5])
{
        if ((4000<rgb_readings[0]<2300)&(2450<rgb_readings[1]<1750)&(850<rgb_readings[2]<400)&(800<rgb_readings[3]<400)) //red
        {
            block [p] = 0;
            //r = r+1;
        }
            else if ((rgb_c[0]>1000)&(rgb_r[1]<1000)&(rgb_g[2]>2000)&(rgb_b[3]<1000)) //green
            {
                block [p] = 1;
                //r = r+1;
            }
                else if ((rgb_c[0]>1000)&(rgb_r[1]<1000)&(rgb_g[2]<1000)&(rgb_b[3]>2000)) //blue
                {
                    block [p] =2;
                    //r = r+1;
                }
                    else if ((rgb_c[0]>1000)&(rgb_r[1]<1000)&(rgb_g[2]>2000)&(rgb_b[3]<1000)) //yellow (edit values)
                    {
                        block [p] = 3;
                       // r = r+1;
                    }
                        else if ((rgb_c[0]>1000)&(rgb_r[1]<1000)&(rgb_g[2]>2000)&(rgb_b[3]<1000)) //orange (edit Values)
                        {
                            block [p]=4;
                           // r = r+1;
                        }
                            else if ((rgb_c[0]>1000)&(rgb_r[1]<1000)&(rgb_g[2]>2000)&(rgb_b[3]<1000)) //white (edit values)
                            {
                                block [p] =5;
                                //r = r+1;
                            }
                                else if((rgb_c[0]>1000)&(rgb_r[1]<1000)&(rgb_g[2]>2000)&(rgb_b[3]<1000)) //black (edit values)
                                {
                                    block [p]=6;
                                    //r = r+1;
                                }

}                         

void prox_sensor()
{
    uint8_t dist;

    TOF_sensor.VL6180_Init();
    pc.printf("TOF Sensor");
    wait(2);
    //lcd.cls(); lcd.locate(0,0);

        //lcd.cls();
        dist = TOF_sensor.getDistance();
        pc.printf("D=%d",dist);
        wait(1);
        //lcd.locate(0,0);
}




    void colourresult(int p, int block[5],int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int b0,int b1,int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5)
{
    for (p = 0;p<6;p++)
    {
        coloursensorread (int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b)
        rgb_process(int p,int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int block [5])
        wait(1);
    }
     b0 = block [0];
     b1 = block [1];
     b2 = block [2];
     b3 = block [3];
     b4 = block [4];
     b5 = block [5];
    pc.printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5);
}



void ReadData(int p, int block[5],int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int b0,int b1,int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5)
{
    uint8_t dist;
    TOF_sensor.VL6180_Init();

    for (;;)
    {
        //lcd.cls();
        dist = TOF_sensor.getDistance();
        //lcd.locate(0,0);
        pc.printf("Distance=%d", dist);
        wait(1);

        if (dist>99)
        {
            colourresult(int p, int block[5],int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int b0,int b1,int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5);
            return ReadData(int p, int block[5],int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int b0,int b1,int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5);
            }
            else {
                wait(3);
                return ReadData(int p, int block[5],int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int b0,int b1,int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5);
                }
            }
    }

 int main()
 {
     int rgb_readings[3];
     int block [5];
     int b0;
     int b1;
     int b2;
     int b3;
     int b4;
     int b5;
     int rgb_c;
     int rgb_r;
     int rgb_g;
     int rgb_b;

     int p;
     ReadData(int p, int block[5],int rgb_readings[3],int rgb_c,int rgb_r,int rgb_g,int rgb_b,int b0,int b1,int b2,int b3,int b4,int b5);
```

Comment: You should include a log of the errors Mervin.. It will be easier to help you

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy Already edited the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want help debugging your code I suggest sharing a link that can be imported into the online compiler. Otherwise I could wind up using a different version of the libraries or other things.

Please share a link to your code so we can try to help.

-Austin
arm Mbed

Answer (score 0):

You are passing rgb_readings[3] to the function which is an integer (at fourth index of an array). In the function, you are treating rgb_readings as an array although it's just an integer. In the function definition, keep the brackets empty int rgb_readings[] if you want to use the array and then just call it without any index in main application code.